# CSS - how to put a dark layer over a picture?

Tags: html, css, angular

In my angular project I have following task to do.

[image]

This is just a design template, not my actual code.

So far I have made the right picture by having a `div` and setting the background image.

But now I dont know how to put a dark layer on the page (like on the left side). The logic is no problem, but I dont know how to achieve it with CSS.

How do I do it?

Comment: You can use `opacity:` 

Here is an [example and more information about this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)

Comment: @JulianDotExe thanks for your comment. I dont think opacity will do the trick here, since it only makes the element more transparent. I would still need that deep dark blue layer over it

Answer (score 2):

You can do this really simply let's suppose you have a div and you can style according to following rules, you can also replace with your element id or css class with **div**:

```
div{
  position:relative;
}

div:after {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: change "reletive" to "relative"

Comment: thanks for your answer - could you elaborate your code more? I dont fully understand what you did here

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `div` over your image and style it the way you want it to.
If you make it black and put opacity on the element, it will get more transparent, which makes it look like its a little darker
Note that you will have to have the `z-index` set accordingly for it to work.
example:

```
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
```

Alternative you could try to add a shadow with `background: linear-gradient()`
example:

```
background: linear-gradient(to top, #3204fdba, #9907facc), url(https://picsum.photos/1280/853/?random=1) no-repeat top center;
```